# Linking external JavaScript file to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and trying to link my JavaScript code to HTML.
Along with the code mentioned below I have also tried below variations in script tag in HTML but none of them worked.

Kindly let me know how to link my external file to HTML.

Here is my folder structure:

[image: structure]

Examples of what I have tried -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/vehicle.js">            
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Source Pakages/js/vehicle.js">            
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/vehicle.js">            
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../vehicle.js">            
    </script>
```

index.html -

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="G:\ajaxx\src\java\js\vehicle.js">            
    </script>

</head>
<body onload = "loadMovies()">
    <div id = "p1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

vehicle.js -

```
function loadMovies()
{
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = ' <select>'+
        ' <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>'+
        ' <option value="saab">Saab</option>'+
        '<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>'+
        '<option value="audi">Audi</option>'+
        '</select>'
}
```

Comment: `src="../Source Pakages/js/vehicle.js"`

Comment: Small note to G:\path: the path is loaded *by the browser* so the path needs to be absolute to *the browsers view* so always protocol://yourserver.com/path/to/file

Answer (score 1):

Also, put your function loadMovies() inside script tag

```
    <script>
    function loadMovies() {
     ...
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Source Packages/js/vehicle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please check the directory properly

Comment: sorry about that. I was editing it when you commented. but thank you for pointing out

Comment: I tried the above code and to run the program in chrome and edge browser but it still shows a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to adapt code that you copied since your `loadMovies()` function has nothing to do with movies. It's okay to borrow code and adapt it to fit your situation, but you should change names to fit functionality. It makes your code easier to read.

If your JavaScript file was in the same directory as your HTML file, you could just use `<script src="vehicle.js"></script>`, but it's not which means that you have to follow the directory tree to the location of the .js file. In your case, that means going up two levels, and then down two levels like this. `<script src="../../Source Packages/js/vehicle.js"></script>`. I'm also assuming that the JavaScript that you are showing after your closing `</html>` tag is the contents of your .js file... right?

Since you are on a Windows machine, your file path will look a little different, but not much. You simply change the '/' to '\' and it should all work. Here are two examples. The first is for a 'NIX machine (Unix, Linux, OSX, etc) and the second (which would apply to you) is for a windows machine. Note that while your pc may be Windows based, the server your code ends up on may not be, so it's important to know the difference.

(For 'NIX Machines)
index.html -

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Source Packages/js/vehicle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload = "loadVehicles()">
    <div id = "p1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

vehicle.js -

```
function loadVehicles() {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = ' <select>'+
        ' <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>'+
        ' <option value="saab">Saab</option>'+
        '<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>'+
        '<option value="audi">Audi</option>'+
        '</select>';
}
```

(For Windows Machines)
index.html -

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..\..\Source Packages\js\vehicle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload = "loadVehicles()">
    <div id = "p1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

vehicle.js -

```
function loadVehicles() {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = ' <select>'+
        ' <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>'+
        ' <option value="saab">Saab</option>'+
        '<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>'+
        '<option value="audi">Audi</option>'+
        '</select>';
}
```

This of course assumes that the folder structure is [image]

Comment: Yes I had copied the code from one of my previous examples that I was trying.
As the output wasn't coming hence the main focus was on getting it.
Once the code works fine I would edit the name.

Yes the code after </html> is my javascript code.

Comment: @krishna Did you try it with the path that I suggested?

Comment: Yes I tried all the combinations mentioning below and tried checking the output in chrome and edge browser but the output was a blank screen on both the browsers.
If possible kindly try the code on your system and advise if it works fine.
IDE used by me is Netbeans 8.1

<script type="text/javascript" src="vehicle.js">
        </script>

<script  src="vehicle.js">
        </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Source Packages/js/vehicle.js"></script>

<script  src="../../Source Packages/js/vehicle.js"></script>

Comment: @krishna I've updated my answer. The solution I posted works on my system.

Answer (score -1):

use this following code,

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Source Pakages/js/vehicle.js">            
    </script>
</head>
<body onload = "loadMovies()">
    <div id = "p1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the above code and to run the program in chrome and edge browser but it still shows a blank screen.